# Clear fields in Form when a certain field is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem** I have the following script that clears certain fields when particular fields are selected:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $zip = $('#zip');
        var $city = $('#city');
        var $hospital = $('#hospital');
        var $miles = $('#miles');

        $zip.on("change",function(){
            $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
            $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
        });

        $city.on("change",function(){
            $zip.val('').trigger('input');
            $miles.val('').trigger('input');
        });

        $hospital.on("change",function(){
            $zip.val('').trigger('input');
            $miles.val('').trigger('input');
        });

        $zip.one("change", function(){
            $miles.val('').trigger('input');
        });
    });
```

I would like when a user selects a mileage, it will clear the Hospital field and the city field. So i thought I could do the following within the same function:

```
$miles.on("change", function(){
        $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        $hospital.val('').trigger('input');
    });
```

However, it did not clear the fields up for Hospital or city field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you debug this, how does it fail?  Does this `change` event handler get executed at all?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Are the elements found?  What does the HTML for this look like?  If you could produce a live example of this on jsFiddle that would help.

Comment: I have just removed Java tag as the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java.

Comment: I second @David in asking to show the HTML. However, no need for jsFiddle as you could compose a live example directly in your question with a snippet.